# Advanced iOS databases

Tags: iphone, ios, database, ipad, ios5

We are developing an application which needs to deal with some non-trivial amount of structured data. What are the most advanced database libraries for iPhones and iPads?

Comment: I can post the relevant generalized code for sqlite that can be implemented in any application if you need.. coredata is a lot easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two obvious candidates: SQLite or Core Data.

SQLite gives you low level granularity/flexibility, but you have to write more code. SQLite is supposed to be good for even 2GB datasets, although I have not personally tried working with anything this large in iOS.

Core Data abstracts the details away from you, saving you from writing lots of code, but optimisation can get quite involved and there are quite a lot of subtleties to get to grips with.

The initial learning curve (unless you happen to already be a SQL guru) is probably easier with Core Data.

Comment: Core Data is Apples's own technology, right?

Comment: That's correct, although on iOS it actually uses SQLite behind the scenes.

Comment: yes, it is. To clarify also, Core Data is really just wrapping whatever the underlying data store is (which is usually SQLite anyway). edit: beat me by a few seconds!

Answer (score 2):

If you pursue SQLite, you can use the [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) Objective C wrapper, which greatly simplifies the your code. Much, much easier than interfacing with the SQLite3 C interface yourself. I use it with a very complicated SQL database and it's a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use sqlite and coredata as databases(persistent storage) on iPhone.But sqlite scores over coredata if the database gets larger .You have not mentioned the size of your data.For smaller data you can even use plist which is significantly faster but has visible performance issues for larger data.

There are certain wrappers for sqlite3 such as[EntropyDb](http://code.google.com/p/entropydb/) and [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)which you can use.

Both the wrappers are good

Comment: "sqlite scores over coredata if the database gets larger" - This is not true in many cases. In fact, the batched fetching in Core Data can lead to far better performance than raw SQLite for large data sets. Core Data is layered on SQLite anyway, and Apple's engineers do a good job of optimizing their queries and interactions with SQLite better than most of us could.

Comment: Yeah but i tried in my project , data size  over 1 gb has significantly reduced retrieval times with sqlite3..